# Springback in carbon/HSLA steel - cold forming

Tags: metallurgy, metal-folding, metalwork

What are the measurements denoted on top of the YS-t steel lines? Material thickness or bend radius?

`ASM Handbook Volume 14B - Metal Working Sheet Forming - 2006; pg.517 fig. 39`

The only mention of the figure (pg.516):

> The
> amount of springback with a carbon steel and a
> high-strength low-alloy steel is compared in
> Fig. 39.

[image: Fig.39 pg.517 ASM Handbook Volume 14B - Metal Working Sheet Forming]